# drupal 6 facebookshare and TweetMeme now showing up doesn't matter what i do

Tags: facebook, twitter, drupal-6, configure

I'm using 2 modules dedicated for twitter and facebook
http://drupal.org/project/facebookshare
http://drupal.org/project/tweetmeme

they simply don't work (i'm using drupal 6 with v6 downloaded for both)

do I have to do other configuration for them to apear on nodes content?

before I had AddThis (i removed it ), that always has apeared in $links on the content page.
I don't know how the previous admin has configured addthis to show it's content there..
I'm probabbly missing some obvious step into configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both modules let you specify which content types you want the links displayed on. You can configure the settings for Facebookshare via **Admin > Site Configuration > Facebook Share** and Tweetmeme via **Admin > Site Configuration > TweetMeme**.

Comment: Thank you, I was not seeing the obvious, yes it works Very well, thank you so much